# avoiding modulo bias with only single random value

Tags: random, modulo

I want to create a random value between 0 and n. As source I receive a random 256-bit value from an oracle.

Just doing

```
source % (n + 1)
```

introduces modulo bias. Solutions to modulo bias I've seen are doing a while loop until the value lies within the largest multiple of n that fits the source range - but in my case I can draw a random source value only once.

my n is much smaller though, let's say smaller than 2^32. Is there any way I can generate a random value that has no modulo bias in this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator)

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that your random number generator is uniform, there is no way to map it to an unbiased generator on `0` to `n` inclusive unless `n+1` is a divisor of `2^256`. This is because it is impossible to partition a set of size `2^256` into `n+1` equally probable subsets unless `n+1` divides `2^256`. Having said that, if `n` is much smaller than `2^256` the departure from uniformity in doing something like `int(source * (n+1)/(2^256 - 1)` will be negligible.

Comment: 2^252? Don't you mean 2^256?